# neo4client Merge does not always work

Tags: asp.net, neo4j

```
List<string> names = new List<string>() { "Alice", "Bob", "Sara", "Maria"}; 
        foreach (string n in names)
        {
            db.Cypher
           .Merge("(a:New)")
           .Set("a.Name = $n")
           .WithParam("n", n)
           .ExecuteWithoutResults();
        }
```

Creates only one vertex instead of four (not necessarily the first element of the list).
The same problem with Parallel.Foreach and with single method calls.
On a local and remote database.
VS 2017 preview core 2.1 & VS 2017 core 2.0

Comment: As a side note, this foreach approach won't be efficient for larger collections. Look instead to using `unwind()` so you can create all the nodes for your entire collection in a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your code to this:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>() { "Alice", "Bob", "Sara", "Maria"}; 
        foreach (string n in names)
        {
            db.Cypher
           .Merge("(a:New {Name:$n})")
           .WithParam("n", n)
           .ExecuteWithoutResults();
        }
```

In this case, you are asking Neo4j to create (or not) a node with the label `New` AND with a property `Name` equals to `$n`.

In your case, you are just asking to create (or not) a node with the label `New`, and then its property `Name` to `$n`.
So it's normal in this case to only have one node.

Comment: @a1oleg Think of MERGE as a MATCH, and if the match fails, then a CREATE. What you were doing before with merge was matching to the same node over and over. You need to include the property in the merge to differentiate it.